# Move existing hole on the flat model

Tags: modeling

I've got an object like a cup (of 2mm thickness) an a hole on its flat bottom. I need to move that hole left or right on the same surface. the dimensions of the hole should stay the same.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Make the hole an edge loop and then hit <kbd>G</kbd> followed by an axis key, that is x, y or z, to move it along the red, green or blue line that appears.